# Google Play Billing 1.0 No interface method getBuyIntentExtraParams

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-billing, play-billing-library

I would like to add the new Google play billing library to my project `com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0` -> [lien](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/google-play-billing-library-10-released.html?m=1)

But when I run:

```
final BillingFlowParams.Builder builder = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
            .setSku(sku)
            .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
int resultCode = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, builder.build());
```

I've this issue :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getBuyIntentExtraParams(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/os/Bundle;)Landroid/os/Bundle; in class Lcom/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService' appears in /data/app/{MY_PAKAGE_NAME}-eHTcC-Sp4zY08KZcxkl7fQ==/base.apk:classes97.dex)
```

BillingClientImpl.java:332

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it. Otherwise, it's not that easy for developers to find the solution if they ever met to a similar problem in future. Thank you!

Comment: @goRGon done ;)

Comment: Great! Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I found why. It's not a problem with the Android build of the device.
It's because there already was an `IInAppBillingService.aidl` in our project. Once I removed it and clean the project everything is working properly. -> [Github Issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/86#issuecomment-332369494)